# HTTParty authentication problem

Tags: ruby, https, httparty

I am trying to log in with HTTParty.
I followed the instruction and still can't get it to work.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class LAShowRoom
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'www.lashowroom.com'
  #debug_output

  def initialize email, password
    @email = email
    response = self.class.get('/login.php')
    response = self.class.post(
      '/login.php',
      :body => { :login_id => email, :login_key => password, :submit_login => 'Log In' },
      :headers => {'Cookie' => response.headers['Set-Cookie']}
    )
    @response = response
    @cookie = response.request.options[:headers]['Cookie']
  end

  def login_response
    @response
  end

  def welcome_page
    self.class.get("/announce.php", :headers => {'Cookie' => @cookie})
  end

  def logged_in?
    welcome_page.include? "Kevin"
  end
end

la_show_room = LAShowRoom.new('my_email', 'my_password')
puts "Logged in: #{la_show_room.logged_in?}"
```

As far as I know, HTTParty handles https automatically.
Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 3):

Yes, HTTParty handles HTTPS automatically, but you still need to declare HTTPS. Try

```
base_uri 'https://…'
```

How else is HTTParty supposed to know? ;-)